# How do I perform a regular expression on multiple .txt files in a folder (Python)?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I'm trying to open up 32 .txt files, extract some text from them (using RegEx) and then save them as individual files again(later on in the project I'm hoping to collate them together). I've tested the RegEx on a single file and it seems to work:

```
import os
import re
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\garet\OneDrive - University of Exeter\Masters\Year Two\Dissertation planning\Manual scrape\Finished years proper')
with open('1988.txt') as txtfile:
    text= txtfile.read()
#print(len(text)) #sentences in text

start = r'Body\n\n\n'

docs = re.findall(start, text)
print('Found the start of %s documents.' % len(docs))
end = r'Load-Date:'
print('Found the end of %s documents.' % len(docs))
docs = re.findall(end, text)
regex = start+r'(.+?)'+end
articles = re.findall(regex, text, re.S)
print('You have now parsed the 154 articles so only the body of content remains. All metadata has been removed.')
print('Here is an example of a parsed article:', articles[0])
```

Now I want to perform the exact same thing on all my .txt files in that folder, but I can't figure out how to. I've been playing around with For loops but with little success. Currently I have this:

```
import os
import re
finished_years_proper= os.listdir(r'C:\Users\garet\OneDrive - University of Exeter\Masters\Year Two\Dissertation\Manual scrape\Finished years proper')
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\garet\OneDrive - University of Exeter\Masters\Year Two\Dissertation\Manual scrape\Finished years proper')
print('There are %s .txt files in this folder.' % len(finished_years_proper))

if i.endswith(".txt"):
    with open(finished_years_proper + i, 'r') as all_years:
        for line in all_years:
            start = r'Body\n\n\n'
            docs = re.findall(start, all_years)
            end = r'Load-Date:'
            docs = re.findall(end, all_years)
            regex = start+r'(.+?)'+end
            articles = re.findall(regex, all_years, re.S)
```

However, I'm returning a type error:

```
 File "C:\Users\garet\OneDrive - University of Exeter\Masters\Year Two\Dissertation\Method\Python\untitled1.py", line 15, in <module>
        with open(finished_years_proper + i, 'r') as all_years:

    TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "str") to list
```

I'm unsure how to proceed... I've seen on other forums that I should convert something into a string, but I'm not sure what to convert or even if this is the right way to proceed. Any help with this would be really appreciated!

---

After taking Benedictanjw's into my codes I've ended up with this:
Hi, this is what I ended up with:

all_years= []
for fyp in finished_years_proper: #fyp is each text file in folder
    with open(fyp, 'r') as year:
        for line in year: #line is each element in each text file in folder
            start = r'Body\n\n\n'
            docs = re.findall(start, line)
            end = r'Load-Date:'
            docs = re.findall(end, line)
            regex = start+r'(.+?)'+end
            articles = re.findall(regex, line, re.S)
            all_years.append(articles) #append strings to reflect RegEx
            parsed_documents= all_years.append(articles) 
            print(parsed_documents) #returns None. Apparently this is okay.

Does the 'None' mean that the parsing of each file is successful (as in it emulates the result I had when I tested the RegEx on a single file)? And if so, how can I visualise my output without returning None.  Many thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem shows because `finished_years_proper` is a list and in your line:

```py
with open(finished_years_proper + i, 'r') as all_years:
```

you are trying to concatenate `i` with that list. I presume you had accidentally defined `i` elsewhere as a string. I guess you probably want to do something like:

```py
all_years = []
for fyp in finished_years_proper:
  with open(fyp, 'r') as year:
    for line in year:
      ... # your regex search on year
      all_years.append(xxx)
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response, I really appreciate it! I haven't actually defined 'i'- I realised it was a useless line because every file in the folder is a .txt file. I've tried

Comment: My pleasure :) Please see edited version of answer without the condition

Comment: It returns 'None' (which apparently means that it's worked..?). I would like to save the files and visualise them now to double-check. What is the best way of going about this?